# Assign many items to one category - OneToMany Relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I want to assign many items to one category. I'm using Symfony 2.6.7.

I'm not at the owning side here. If I open this URI:

/category/2/assign

```
[x] Item 1
[x] Item 2
(Save Button)
```

I have the possibility to chose many items with checkboxes.

This is my db table "Item", where I want to connect the both:

```
id | category_id
```

It is an OneToMany relation, where One = Category and Many = Items.

How can I assign the both here?

It is already working, when I edit one item and than select a category to this item. Now I'm on the category side and here I want select many items to this one category. Can someone help, please? :-)

Comment: Take a look at the [Collection field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)

Comment: hm.. thank you, but I don't want do "add" items - I only want to assign existing items to an existing category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Category')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Category entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->bind($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        foreach ($editForm->get('items')->getData()->getValues() as $u)
            $u->setCategory($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('category_show', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return $this->render('YourBundle:Category:edit.html.twig', array(
                'entity' => $entity,
                'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

See, In Symfony2 the entity with the property with the inversedBy doctrine comment is the one that is supposed to take action when you want to create a new link between the two tables. That is why you can assign a category to an item but not add items to a category.

The above code is a standard CRUD-generated Symfony2 **updateAction** function. The only tweak is the **foreach**, thus forcibly assigning a category to every item you selected in the form.

It's rudimentary but it works.

NOTE: I did not include a workaround for REMOVING items from a category, but a similar approach would do it. Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** FOR REMOVING ITEMS:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Category')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Category entity.');

        }
        //new line
        $before = $entity->getItems()->getValues();

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->bind($request);

        //new line
        $after = $entity->getItems()->getValues();

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            //new lines
            $UNselected = array_diff($before, $after);
            foreach ($UNselected as $u) {
                $u->setCategory(null);
            }

            foreach ($after as $u) {
                $u->setCategory($entity);
            }
            //new lines - end

            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('category_show', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return $this->render('YourBundle:Category:edit.html.twig', array(
                    'entity' => $entity,
                    'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

Same function, just include the new lines.

**array_diff** will return the items that were linked to the category entity before the submit and are not after the submit, then with the **foreach** again you can assign **null** as each of those items' category, i.e.: break the link between them.

The second **foreach** does the same as the original answer's. Just try it like this now and tell me if it worked.

Again, rudimentary, again, should work.

Comment: Hmm.. I stuck with the remove part. May it's possible to explain also the remove part, please? :-)